# Is it possible to create a private or internal ember.js addon?

Tags: ember.js

**My Use Case**

I work for a company that maintains multiple (like 7 or 8) different websites using Ember.js. Most of these sites have an almost identical navigation bar at the top. The very few changes are things that could easily be inputted as if it were a component or add-on. In order to increase the modularity of our code, I think it would be really cool to import most of our navigation bar code into an add-on and use it across all of our sites.

One of the problems with this approach, however, is that our navigation bar is too internal to want to publish it as a public add-on (only my company would ever need to use it). And so I would rather not post it as a public add-on.

Is this a possible use case for Ember Addons? If so, how might we consider implementing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully used the following approach in the past:

1. Create your addon
2. Create a symlink in your global node_modules folder (`cd /your-addon-folder && npm link`)
3. Go to the website project and create a symlink there, too (`cd /your-homepage && npm link your-addon-package-name`)
4. Use your addon

This happens locally on your machine, your addon is neither published to nor consumed from the npmjs.com registry.

The be on the safe side, you can use the `private` flag in your addon's `package.json` and also make it unlicensed:

```
...
"private": true,
"license": "UNLICENSED",
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a big use case for [Yarn Workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/). They allow you to create a local package that is shared amongst all the apps in the workspace. These are very usable with Ember.js and Lenny Burdette gave a [talk about them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulWhjL0Aj5s) at the Ember SF meetup last year. If you're building a lot of apps together this is also a nice way to keep your dependency version in sync between the apps.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your websites are under a common project you could consider creating the navigation or all common components as an `in-repo-addon` which would serve the purpose of being private plus acting as an addon. To create an in-repo-addon you can use the following command

```
ember g in-repo-addon <private-addon-name>

# To create a component inside the addon, use:

ember g component <component-name> -ir <private-addon-name>

# Instead of '-ir', you could also use '--in-repo-addon'
# Also 'g' in the above commands = 'generate'
```

Running the above command would create a `lib/<private-addon-name>` folder under which you can use the components, commons, etc.

Refer: https://ember-cli.com/extending/#in-repo-addons

Answer (score 1):

You could publish to a private npm registry. you could use npmjs orgs, however there is various software (some free) out there to do this.